# Find a color's pixel coordinates

Tags: c#, image-processing, rgb, pixel, argb

I am making a program in Visual Studio C# that can detect a color, then find the x, y coordinate of that pixel with that color. I have done research, but all I can find is you already give the coordinate, and it senses the color, that's not what I want though, I want to give the color, and it finds the coordinate. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: How are you going to give the color RGB or Just a color Blue ?

Comment: Most likely RGB, but I'm not really sure what the function for this... that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: Where would you find that information? You should obviously loop through all x's and y's, testing whether they are in the color you seek.

Answer (score 4):

You can feed the image to a Bitmap object and then call the getPixel(x, y) method to get a pixel at a specific point.  Since a Bitmap object has the dimensions of the image, you can iterate over every pixel (YIKES!), testing for a match with desired color.  getPixel() returns a Color object, which you can work with.  Here's something I worked up super fast.  pictureBox1 is a PictureBox element on my form.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
Color c = b.GetPixel(0,0);
```

Remember, though, that the search for the matching pixel is worse case O(n) where n is the number of pixels in the image.  For small and maybe medium-sized pictures this isn't too bad, but for huge images, you might notice your program hang.

Comment: For performance, you might try to break up the search into multiple segments and search through the smaller segments.

Answer (score 3):

You can do what @kevin628 said, but add a `for` statements, so it would search every pixel like this:

```
    private void GetPixels()
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

        List<Color> colorList = new List<Color>
        {

        };

        for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; x++)
            {
                colorList.Add(b.GetPixel(x, y));
            }
        }
    }
```

Then using [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPNLf.png), you get something like this(not the whole this as it is ~50000 lines):

> Color [A=255, R=247, G=240, B=136]
>   Color [A=255, R=252, G=247, B=155]
>   Color [A=255, R=242, G=238, B=164]
>   Color [A=255, R=79, G=124, B=103]
>   Color [A=255, R=79, G=124, B=103]
>   Color [A=255, R=0, G=42, B=17]
>   Color [A=255, R=16, G=104, B=90]
>   Color [A=255, R=15, G=114, B=109]
>   Color [A=255, R=33, G=125, B=124]
>   Color [A=255, R=11, G=83, B=80]
>   Color [A=255, R=36, G=72, B=68]
>   Color [A=255, R=151, G=156, B=150]
>   Color [A=255, R=90, G=70, B=59]
>   Color [A=255, R=147, G=109, B=88]
>   Color [A=255, R=252, G=204, B=164]
>   Color [A=255, R=220, G=175, B=134]
>   Color [A=255, R=219, G=187, B=162]
>   Color [A=255, R=126, G=104, B=91]
>   Color [A=255, R=108, G=94, B=93]
>   Color [A=255, R=241, G=235, B=239]
>   Color [A=255, R=139, G=137, B=142]
>   Color [A=255, R=83, G=92, B=101]
>   Color [A=255, R=146, G=172, B=187]
>   Color [A=255, R=17, G=62, B=85]
>   Color [A=255, R=40, G=106, B=138]
>   Color [A=255, R=33, G=116, B=146]
>   Color [A=255, R=5, G=96, B=117]
>   Color [A=255, R=0, G=79, B=84]
>   Color [A=255, R=6, G=94, B=80]
>   Color [A=255, R=27, G=114, B=98]
>   Color [A=255, R=40, G=130, B=131]
>   Color [A=255, R=19, G=116, B=125]
>   Color [A=255, R=21, G=128, B=134]
>   Color [A=255, R=5, G=119, B=120]
>   Color [A=255, R=8, G=120, B=121]
>   Color [A=255, R=11, G=107, B=105]
>   Color [A=255, R=46, G=113, B=106]
>   Color [A=255, R=21, G=70, B=49]
>   Color [A=255, R=45, G=123, B=99]

Then to test for a color, just do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colorList.Count; i++)
{
    Color c = Color.Black;

    if (c == colorList[i])
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Load up your texture as array of bytes. For example, if your texture is 2x2 size,
it should look something like:
000111222333
Where:
000 - RGB at (0,0)
111 - RGB at (1,0)
222 - RGB at (0,1)
333 - RGB at (1,1) 
000 or 111 means it has 3 bytes, where
each byte is red,or green, or blue.
Once you done that, you can loop through all x and y,
and check if color at current position matches your searched color.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method you've already found for this. Check every pixel at every coordinate to find a color that is equal to the color that was input by the user. Start at 0, 0. Then increment the X value until it is at the end of the row of pixels. Each time the X value is at the end of the row, increment the Y value and reset X to 0. Once you get a color value that is equal to the color value that was input by the user, the last used X and Y coordinates before finding a match are what is given back to the user.